# How to pragmatically log in to a website using WKWebView?

Tags: html, swift, authentication, wkwebview

I'm trying to log into a website using an app. The project has two view controllers, one with a Login UI I made and the other with a WKWebView. Basically I want to take the user-entered parameters and send them to the WKWebView, login, and return data to be presented on another view controller.

Note: I have already tried looking for an API, but this website doesn't have one accessable

Here is how I am currently doing it, but I'm running into a force unwrapping returned Nill error.

**View Controller with WebView**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class Web_View: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {



var webView: WKWebView!
var viewControllerManager : ViewController!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let HAC_URL = URL(string:"https://hac.friscoisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fhomeaccess%2f")
    let request = URLRequest(url: HAC_URL!)
    webView.load(request)
}

//loadsBackgroundView
override func loadView() {
    let webConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfig)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

//Username manager
func webViewDidFinishLoadUsername() {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementByTagName(\"input\")[2].value = \(viewControllerManager.username)") {(result, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print(result!)
        }
        else
        {
            print(error!)
        }
    }
}
//Password manager
func webViewDidFinishLoadPassword() {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementByTagName(\"input\")[1].value = \(viewControllerManager.password)") {(result, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print(result!)
        }
        else
        {
            print(error!)
        }
    }

}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
}
```

**Login UI View Controller**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

//Outlets and variables
let webViewControllerObject = Web_View()


var username : String = ""
var password : String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!


//Allows user to "touch off" the keyboard
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}



//Gathers data and holds in two varables, sends username params
@IBAction func loginRequest(_ sender: Any) {

    username = usernameTextField.text!
    password = passwordTextField.text!

    if (username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty)
    {
        errorLabel.text = "Please enter a valid login"
    }

    else if (!(username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty))
    {
        webViewControllerObject.webViewDidFinishLoadUsername()
        webViewControllerObject.webViewDidFinishLoadPassword()
    }

    else
    {
        print("rough")
    }

}


}
```

If there is any better way to do this, please inform me

**Edit**
This is the line I think needs fixing

var webView: WKWebView!

var viewControllerManager : ViewController!

**The error pops up on this line**
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementByTagName(\"input\")[2].value = (viewControllerManager.username)") {(result, error) in

I have a hunch it is because I force unwrapped again

Comment: I just simulated what you’re trying to do with most of what you have and it looks like you’re trying to evaluate the tags on the website before you’ve even requested the URL

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid forced unwrapping like this for example:

> username = usernameTextField.text!

```swift
if let usernameText = usernameTextField.text { 
    username = usernameText
}
```

As I cannot add comments yet, I assumed that your only problem is "***force unwrapping returned Nill error***". Above is my suggestion to avoid it.

Comment: I don't think the username and password line is the issue, but yes you are right that appears to be my only problem so far. I will highlight the line I think is causing the issue, and will change it to what you suggested. Any other ideas?

Comment: I usually do it more this way..

`let usernameText = usernameTextField.text ?? ""`

sometimes I put something more like "no username" instead of blank... depends on the app and whether it's OK to not have a username

Answer (score 0):

Hidde the webView

```
webView.isHidden = true
webView.isHidden = false
```